# Не проходит запрос INSERT mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Решил перейти на mysqli, но в некоторых вещах еще не так силен, как с устаревшем диалекте ибо еще не до конца разобрался в механике этого. Прошу помощи.

Что я тут сделал не так?

```
$db = new mysqli($hystbdserver,$hystbduser,$hystbdpassword,$hystbdname);
$db->set_charset("utf8");
$add = $db->stmt_init();
$add->prepare("INSERT INTO hystsukategories (name,image,text) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$add->bind_param('sss',$name,$resize,$text);    
$name = $db->real_escape_string($name);
$resize = $db->real_escape_string($resize);
$text = $db->real_escape_string($text);
$add->execute();
mysqli_close($db);
```

выдает вот такие ошибки

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: invalid
>   object or resource mysqli_stmt in ##### on line #

---

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute() [mysqli-stmt.execute]: invalid object
>   or resource mysqli_stmt in ##### on line #

Comment: Ну а на какую конкретно строку указывает первая ошибка?

Comment: real_escape_string надо вообще-то убрать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверяйте возвращаемые значения

> mysqli_stmt::prepare
>
> Возвращаемые значения
>
> Возвращает **TRUE** в случае успешного завершения или **FALSE** в случае возникновения ошибки.

```
if (!$add->prepare("INSERT INTO hystsukategories (name,image,text) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"))
  die($add->error);
```

Comment: Спасибо выдало ошибку, показало что ошибка в значении поля